Need to figure out the resistor requirements in this parallel circuit

Here's the conundrum, I
need to find out what resistors to use in this circuit,
As I don't know enough about electronics to confidently understand and any help would be greatly appreciated.
The circuit would work as followed: when switch one is closed (furthest left) this should turn on an indicator LED (2 V, 0.02 A) and then allow voltage to the second switch (furthest right), working as a sort of indicator or primer switch for the second. When the second switch is closed as well as the first, the second switch should turn on another indicator light telling us that both switches are closed and there's voltage across the circuit/ there's voltage traveling to the other components.
My problem is that I don't understand enough to find out the value of the resistors required for when both switches are closed as to power both LEDs (2 V, 0.02 A), component x (12 V, 0.2 A) and component Y (12 V, 15 A).
Once again any help greatly appreciated.

You are not asking a question. If the question is how to calculate a resistor for a LED when supply voltage, LED voltage and current is known, there are millions of hobbyist websites explaining just that, even Wikipedia, and also it has been asked here and answered before.

Confirm if +/- 12 V or  just 12V with +/- leads!
Then instead of two 20 mA circuits in parallel,  make it two LEDs sharing 20 mA in series.   You subtract the forward voltage Vf for each LED to get the remainder drop for R.  Ohms Law for  R= V/I  If white = 3.1V then 12-3.1-3.1 = 5.8V across the R= V/I = 5.8/0.02A 290 Ohms.  choose the closest 330 for longer life or 270 for slightly brighter  Pd=116 mW which 50% of a 1/4W resistor max, which is a good limit but is still very hot to touch ~ 60 'C rise

Since all the circuits are in parallel they can be considered independently - similar to the lights in your house being independent of one another.
Assuming a 2 V drop for an LEDs that leaves 10 V across the resistor. \$ R = \frac VI = \frac {10}{0.02} = 500 \ \Omega \$. 470 Ω is the nearest E12 series standard value and that would be fine.
Tips:

Number the components in your schematics. SW1, SW2, R1, R2, D1, D2, etc. It makes it much easier to discuss.
Note that (reading from left to right) D2 and D3 will turn on together.
I've assumed your power supply is 12 V. Normally we would "ground" one of the supply pins - typically the negative, and that would result in +12 V and 0 V power rails. If you truly have ±12 V supplies then you have 24 V between the power rails.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Hi thankyou for the quick response and tips for discussion (and yes I believe that from left to right when both SW1 & SW2 are closed LED 1 & 2 should be turned on) but from what I'm understanding,
should all of the resistors have 470Ω or just the ones once SW2 is closed?
thanks again

Note the supplies are +12 and -12, not +12 V and ground. Therefore there is 22 V across the LED, not 10.

@ThePhoton, yes, I did notice that and meant to comment on it in my "Tips". Since there is no ground in the circuit I took it to mean 12V+ and 12V- rather than +12 V and -12 V. The OP may not be aware of the convention.

@GodJihyo, thanks for the fix. I was using HTML entities for the Ω character but forgot the closing ;.  It gives a nicer appearance than mixing MathJAX inline with text: 470 Ω versus $ 470 \Omega $ when I think is nicer when one isn't writing an actual equation as it doesn't break the text visual flow. Most of what you need is available including all the Greek letters. &Omega; &omega; &mu; &pm; etc. They work in the posts but not in the comments.

@Transistor Ah, didn't know that, thanks. Usually I use ALT+234 outside of equations but I was on my phone at the time and there's no ALT key.

There is no way you can adjust the resistors you have in your diagram to lead t the Y component having 12 V across it. Once the switches are closed, component Y is connected directly across the +12 and -12 supplies, therefore it has 24 V across it regardless of any of the other resistor choices.
Without knowing more about component Y (Is 15 A a maximum rating or a supply requirement? What is its IV characteristic?) it's difficult to know how to change your circuit to accommodate this part. Maybe you should just connect it between +12 V and ground. Maybe you should use a switching converter to reduce the applied voltage to 12 V. Without knowing what it actually is, it's not possible to know what's the right solution.

I’d bet it’s a 12V supply or battery and they marked it -12V to mean the negative terminal. Components x and y are both 12V and they probably think they need the resistor on x to limit it to 0.2A. Common things for beginners to do. Hopefully they’ll come back and clarify that.

A switch is just a resistance with two possible values, 0Ω when it is closed, and ∞Ω (infinite resistance) when open. When closed, it's just like a wire connection, having no electrical resistance. Analysis with both switches in your schematic closed is easier if you imagine that they are replaced with 0Ω wires:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Those wire connections all form a single node, bringing all points anywhere on that node to the same potential, +12V.  With both switches closed, P, A and C become the same node, with the same potential +12V everywhere along it: \$V_G=V_E=V_C=V_A=V_P=+12V\$, just as all points on the negative supply node Q have the same potential \$V_H=V_F=V_D=V_B=V_Q=-12V\$.
From the perspective of each "load+resistor" pair (such as D1 & R1), the voltage across each pair is now \$V_P-V_Q=(+12V)-(-12V)=+24V\$ (as shown on the voltmeters), and it is this potential difference that drives our decision making for the values of R1 and R2. Both LEDs are identical, both resistors are identical, and both pairs have the same potential difference across them. Assuming the goal is to have the same LED current in both cases, our calculations are identical for each:

simulate this circuit
The total voltage 24V is shared between each element, which is a consequence of Kirchhoff's voltage law. LED D1 takes \$V_D=2V\$, and resistor R1 gets the remainder:
$$ V_{R1} = V_S - V_D = 24V - 2V = 22V $$
Ohm's law will tell us what resistance is needed, if we aim to have 20mA flowing:
$$ R_1 = R_2 = \frac{V_{R1}}{I_{R1}} = \frac{22V}{20mA} = 1.1k\Omega $$
This will work for the LEDs, but same cannot be said for loads X and Y. Can you guarantee what voltage will exist across those loads with currrent flowing through them? The LEDs have the interesting property that they will develop 2V almost regardless of their current, can you say the same about X and Y?
If not, then the above steps won't work for them. However, there are some things you can be sure of; when both switches are closed, the total potential difference across each load+resistor pair is:
$$ (V_E - V_F) = 24V $$
$$ (V_G - V_H) = 24V $$
Those 24V will be shared between each individual element of the pair:
$$ V_X + V_{R3} = 24V $$
$$ V_Y + V_{R4} = 24V $$
Given your dual supplies of ±12V, presumably you have access to the mid-point ground node, 0V. If so, there is an easy way to ensure that elements X and Y have exactly 12V across them:

simulate this circuit
We dispense with R3 and R4. The potentials at the top of X and Y are now \$V_E=V_G=+12V\$. The potentials at the bottom of X and Y are \$V_F=V_H=0V\$. Therefore the potential differences are:
$$ V_X = V_E - V_F = (+12V)-(0V) = +12V $$
$$ V_Y = V_G - V_H = (+12V)-(0V) = +12V $$
In other words, both X and Y have 12V across them.
It's not possible to say how much current will flow through X and Y, since that depends of the properties of X and Y. Each will take what it takes, it's not up to you to decide on their behalf. All you can say for sure is that they'll have 12V across them.
One thing to take away here is that R1 and D1 don't actually affect the potential difference between C/E/G and D/F/H. It's not correct to say that they can influence power delivered to any other element following them in the "chain". In your own schematic, each load (such as D1+R1, or X+R3) is connected in "parallel" across the same potential difference, the same source of voltage. Since that source does not change its voltage just because you've connected something new across it (see the caveat below), the voltage across each load doesn't change, the conditions under which each load operates does not change, and the loads are effectively independent of each other.
The caveat is, of course, that there's no such thing as a wire or switch with zero resistance, or a voltage source with no internal resistance. That's why the lights dim when the air-conditioner kicks in. Wire resistance, switch resistance and voltage source internal resistance are ever-present departures from the ideal in every system, and we take measures to mitigate them, like using really fat conductors to get as close to 0Ω as possible.
